# lxml library won't install in virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, debian, lxml, python-venv

OS: Debian GNU/Linux v9

System: Python 3.4.2

Ran command: `sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-lxml python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3-lxml libssl-dev libffi-dev`

I can do the following: `python3` then `import lxml`

**And it works**! :)

I make a virtual environment, `pip3 install` some stuff, and type `pip3 list`

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
asn1crypto      0.24.0
cffi            1.12.2
cryptography    2.6.1
pip             19.0.3
pycparser       2.19
python-dateutil 2.8.0
pytz            2018.9
setuptools      40.8.0
six             1.12.0
```

Then I type: `pip3 install lxml` and get this:

```
cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInithmyjgqp8.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInithmyjgqp8.o
    /tmp/xmlXPathInithmyjgqp8.c:1:26: fatal error: libxml/xpath.h: No such file or directory
     #include "libxml/xpath.h"
                              ^
    compilation terminated.
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

**So it seems lxml can install on system, but not in a virtual environment.  What am I doing wrong, and why is this?**

Comment: You are confusing the meaning of the error. lxml is a python module. It doesn't provide libxml, just the interface. The error is about compiling the interface: you doesn't have the correct file installed: try to install libxml2-dev or something like that, which provide the support file so that `pip` can compile the lxml interface.

Comment: Thank you @GiacomoCatenazzi you are correct!  Great catch!